# Math.Floor on the whole number

Tags: c#, math

I am using Math.Floor method to find out how many times can number a be in number b. In this concrete example, variables are with these values:

```
double a = 1.2; 

double b = 0.1;

double c = Math.Floor(a / b) * b;
```

This returns c = 11 instead of c = 12 as I thought it will. I guess it has something to do with rounding, but how can I get it work properly? When I raise number a to 1,21, it returns 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double` and `float` are internally represented in a way that lacks precision for many numbers, which means that `a` may not be exactly `1.2` (but, say, 1.199999999...) and `b` not exactly `0.1`.

If you want exact precision, for quantities that do not have a margin of error like money, use `decimal`.

Comment: Even `decimal` won't give you "Exact Precision". If it did, then the following code would print "70", but instead it prints "69": `Console.WriteLine(Math.Floor(10m/(1m/7m)));`

Comment: It doesn't have infinite precision, since that would require infinite memory, but it has exact precision for what it can represent, i.e. everything that fits in its 28 decimal digits.

Comment: Ok, I will try decimals. However there might be some other way how to solve my problem. What I have is a length of something. And this something has a smallest piece to which it can be divided, say 0.1m. So if I get number 1.19m I need to return 1.1m. When I get 1.2m then 1.2m is correct result.

Comment: So decimals helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The result of your code is `1.1`.
I am assuming you want to get `1.2`.
You need to use

```cs
double c = Math.Ceiling(a / b) * b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for how Math.Floor works. ..basically , it rounds down ...

My guess would be that with doubles you don't really get 12 as the division (even though this will seems to work: `double d = a/b; // d=12`).

**Solal** pointed to the same, and gave a good advice about decimal :)

Here's what happens with decimals:

```
decimal a = 1.2m; 
decimal b = 0.1m;
decimal c = Math.Floor(a / b) ; // c =12
```

Comment: Ok, I will try decimals. However there might be some other way how to solve my problem. What I have is a length of something. And this something has a smallest piece to which it can be divided, say 0.1m. So if I get number 1.19m I need to return 1.1m. When I get 1.2m then 1.2m is correct result.